# How to resolve this error on oracle?

Tags: oracle

what is this error, I am trying to import some data into oracle and getting this error on a fresh database.

UID-12538: operation generated ORACLE error 12538

ora-12538: TNS:no such protocol adapter

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is lacking a *lot* of information - please add the *exact command* you run, the contents of your tnsnames.ora / sqlnet.ora plus any relevant environment variables (ORACLE_HOME/TNS_ADMIN) that you have changed (and please add this information by 'edit'ing your question, not as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle documentation we see this on the ORA-12538 error

**ORA-12538:    TNS:no such protocol adapter**

**Cause:**  The protocol adapter requested (by way of the '(PROTOCOL=..)'; keyword-value pair in a TNS address) is unknown. If the supplied address is typographically correct then the protocol adapter is not installed.

**Action:**     Install the protocol adapter or correct typographically error, as appropriate. Note: if the supplied address was derived from resolving the service name, check the address in the appropriate file (TNSNAMES.ORA, LISTENER.ORA or SQLNET.ORA).

**Solutions:**

If TNS_ADMIN is set then you should be able to use a network alias, not the full "(DESCRIPTION..."  connect string. The TNS_ADMIN parm tells Oracle clients where to find the tnsnames.ora file.

Setting the ORACLE_HOME environment variable incorrectly on a Windows based system will create this problem.